# Get strings from localizable.strings in Interface Builder MacOs

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have an app with different brandings. Each brand have a `localizable.strings` file which is copied into the Bundle Resources depending on the target brand. Two brands can have the same language but have different wordings and therefore have different `localizable.strings` files. A brand will always only have one language/localization though.

This works well for use directly in the code, but I can't figure out how to access `localizable.strings` in the Interface Builder. Does anyone know how to?

Edit: Other approaches to solve the problem with different brandings are also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Base localization?

[image: Base localization files]

[image: Base localization properties]

If so, each Interface builder file should have its own .strings file, that you can customize per brand.

Comment: I see, thank you. But how do I go about having two .strings files for e.g. English depending on brand?

Comment: You could add a Run Script phase to your project Build Phases that copies a particular brand .strings file into your app bundle.

Comment: Okay. I hoped there was a way where I could use the Localizable.strings file directly in the IB, but I guess not. Thank you very much for your time!